# Do we want Travel.SE drone questions migrated here?

Tags: discussion, migration

Travel.SE has a lot of drone questions and even a drone tag:

- https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drones

Most of them are on topic and about regulations. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke) (a Travel.SE mod) has very kindly offered to migrate some if we want to.

Do we want to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm sorry, this isn't how migrations work.

If a question subject is on topic at a site, it's on topic there. A new site can't ask for those questions to be moved to their site and the older site shouldn't be looking to move those questions, either - particularly not long after the fact. We don't expect all questions about a specific thing to be only on that site.

For example,

- questions about coffee are on topic both on the Coffee site and the Cooking site.
- questions about woodworking are on topic both on Woodworking and Arts & Crafts.
- questions about *The Princess Bride* are on topic on Sci-fi (book or movie) and also on Movies & TV (for the movie) and on Literature (for the book).

This is fine!

While it's kind that the moderator has offered this, as Glorfindel said, it's not actually possible and it's also not appropriate. The one exception would be if Travel decides to make drones off topic entirely. At that point we could investigate it but that's the only time we'd even consider it.

Answer (score 5):

There's one problem with this: ♦ moderators cannot migrate questions [older than 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/295232). So none of the questions in that list can be migrated here.

You can ask for future [drones] questions on Travel Stack Exchange to be migrated here, but generally questions aren't migrated because they are 'better suited' for another site; they're only migrated if they are off-topic.